# How to check if only two certain values exist in a list

Tags: python, for-loop, boolean, nested-lists

I'm trying to make a tic-tac-toe game with python. I was trying to make a function that would show a tie.

I am trying to make a function that checks a nested list to see if there is only the value "X" or "O" and return True if that's the case.

board = [["O","O","O"], ["X", "O", "X"], ["O", "X", "X"]]

I would want this to return True.

board = [[1,"O","O"], ["X", "O", "X"], ["O", "X", "X"]]

I would want this to return False.

I can figure out how to test an entire list to see if one value exists but I don't know how to check for two types of values.

Comment: Please try yourself, then update your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools` and `set operation`, like:

```py
from itertools import chain

def check_board(your_list):
    tmp_set = set(chain(*your_list))
    return len(s - set("OX")) == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [in](http://%20https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_in.asp) keyword to check for presence of an element in a list. 
It also works with nested lists if you provide a list as the element to check for:

```
board = [["X","O","X"], ["O","O","O"], ["O","O","X"]]

if ["X","X","X"] in board:
  print("yes")
```

prints "yes".

To check for both conditions, use the [or](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp) operator:

```
board = [["X","O","X"], ["O","O","O"], ["O","O","X"]]

if ["X","X","X"] in board or ["O","O","O"] in board:
  print("yes")
```